# Date Extraction from Text

Tags: date, nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use Stanford NLP tool to extract dates ( 8/11/2012 ) form text.

Here's [a link](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/ner/process/)! for the demo of this tool

Can u help me in how to train the classifier to identify date ( 8/11/2012 ).

I tried using training data as

Woodhouse   PERS
8/18/2012 Date
,   O
handsome    O

but does not work for same test data .

Answer (score 9):

Using the NLP tool to extract dates from text seems like overkill if this is all you are trying to accomplish. You should consider other options like a simple Java regular expression (eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270195/extracting-dates-from-text-in-java)).

If you are doing something that requires more features from the Stanford NLP tool, take a look at the [SUTime](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml) annotator. Their [demo page](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/sutime/process) will let you get a feel for how it behaves. Make sure to check the option `Read rules from file` and you will see that your date gets annotated.

Usage:

```
SUTime annotations are provided automatically with the StanfordCoreNLP pipeline by including the ner annotator.
```

Answer (score 5):

You can certainly train the CRF-based NER to recognize dates and times. You can see an example of that by running the supplied english.muc.7class.distsim.crf.ser.gz model. See [the FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/crf-faq.shtml#a) for training NER systems. But note that our primary tool for time/date recognition is now regex based: SUTime.  You can also write rules for SUTime for other applications. See the [SUTime page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml) and the link to TokensRegex on that page.

Answer (score 0):

in the sutime/english.sutime.txt line 319, there are few patterns for US tagging:

```
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /yyyy-?MM-?dd-?'T'HH(:?mm(:?ss([.,]S{1,3})?)?)?(Z)?/ } 
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /yyyy-MM-dd/ }  
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /'T'HH(:?mm(:?ss(.,)?)?)?(Z)?/ } 
// Tokenizer "sometimes adds extra slash  
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /yyyy\?/MM\?/dd/ }  
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /MM?\?/dd?\?/(yyyy|yy)/ } 
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /MM?-dd?-(yyyy|yy)/ } 
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /HH?:mm(:ss)?/ }
{ ruleType: "time", pattern: /yyyy-MM/ }
```

just need to add few ruleTypes, to get it the needed order