# Is there a multilingual temporal expression tagger that can run on Hadoop?

Tags: java, datetime, hadoop, nlp, stanford-nlp

I need to extract dates from lots of text. The more languages the better; English,Spanish, and Portuguese at a minimum. Does such a tool exist? In Java and Mavenized? Here's what I've found:

- http://code.google.com/p/heideltime/ many languages and an impressive online demo, but requires some odd external dependencies that I suspect will make cluster deployment hard/impossible
- http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/sutime.shtml Well documented, but English only. Easy to train?
- http://natty.joestelmach.com/ English only
- https://github.com/samtingleff/jchronic English only
- http://code.google.com/p/nltk/source/browse/trunk/nltk_contrib/nltk_contrib/timex.py English only

Where else should I look?

Comment: Heideltime is deployable into UIMA which can run on Hadoop natively. Don't know how you define "odd external dependencies".

Comment: From what I read, I need to have http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/ somewhere locally. I will give the UIMA version a try, though I'm not too sure what UIMA is.

Comment: any advice on how to use UIMA? I've been reading a lot and still cant figure out what it is or why I need it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17283557/do-i-need-to-rewrite-my-entire-java-project-if-i-want-to-use-a-single-uima-depen

Comment: @ThomasJungblut I really don't see how this works. UIMA looks like it needs to read/write many local files, and HeidelTime depends on some perl stuff (ie "TreeTagger"). Nothing here seems like it can run on Hadoop.

Answer (score 0):

You might find [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) useful.

Comment: Does it do temporal tagging?

Answer (score 0):

I've been researching a similar topic. There isn't much documentation out there, but I'll share what I've discovered.

UIMA is essentially a framework that glues together programs ("Annotators") in an analysis pipeline. As unstructured data flows through the pipeline, the annotators extract the useful bits and write it to a data object called the Common Analysis Structure (CAS).

A UIMA pipeline is implemented in Java, and thus runs in a JVM. Tools written in other languages, e.g. Perl, can be brought into the pipeline with an appropriate wrapper.

The pipeline can be run in a MapReduce map task. The digitalPebble Behemoth project provides a convenient way to handle this.