# Phone number and Date of Birth from human speech

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

Is there an effective Natural Language Processor that can fetch the phone number and date of birth from human speech. Each user has a different way of specifying the phone number and date of birth. Hence, converting speech to text and then parsing the text for phone number is not helpful.

Comment: What is you use case? To create a chat bot or to extract these from text in general?

Comment: The use case is to extract the date from the speech.It is not about building chatbot.

Comment: The voice-to-text, text-to-number, text-to-date are well researched and supported by numerous libs and tools, so constitute easiest route. Yet easiest way not necessarily most fun. Direct fetch might happens be more efficient solution but you would need to implement it yourself (probably on top of other tools). I imagine you can download any Deep Learning neural network, erase a top layer or two and retrain for your purporses (that might be more appropriate question for an AI sister site of stackoverflow)

Comment: BTW Watson smart formatting (beta) converts dates, times, numbers, phone numbers, and currency values in final transcripts of US English audio into more readable, conventional forms.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google speech to text api. I had used same for entering account number for blind people. I was working for bank so I there were lots of numbers involved as input eg account number, card number etc.

With Google STT engine you can define custom voice inputs.

Also I had created feedback mechanism using Text to Speech Api so that app can tell if users feedback is invalid and request him to speak again.

You can see code snippet at github. 
https://github.com/hiteshsahu/Android-TTS-STT

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to extract text from speech, there is [plenty of tools](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-top-ten-speech-recognition-APIs), proprietary (nuance), and tinker friendly open source like sphinx, and plenty of tools to extract dates and phones expressed differently. IBM Watson offers one, Smart Formatting beta, to uniform dates and phones in own transcripts. To guess which dates are birthdays you try detect related keywords (birth, born so on) nearby.

For few free alternatives, check

For phone #

https://www.npmjs.com/package/phone-number-extractor

https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

For date extractions check prev questions

[Extracting dates from text in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5270195/extracting-dates-from-text-in-java)

[Best way to identify and extract dates from text Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994396/best-way-to-identify-and-extract-dates-from-text-python)

There is a patent for the process your are asking, but you might have to pay royalties or smth.
http://www.freepatentsonline.com/8416928.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want to fetch the phone number and date of birth from human speech.

So, you can use another option and implement it.

https://cloud.google.com/speech/

This API is really useful for converting your speech to text. I also have this problem at one moment so you can try it too.

The another API which is really good for authentication.

https://api.ai/

I hope it helps you.